# Updating javafx treeview in with progress indicator

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, treeview, concurrentmodification

I am trying to create a class that is basically a treeitem having the file structure of computer (yes, I am trying to create a file manager here). I have set the TreeView to lazy load, and it works well. But it takes sometime with really long directories (directories that have a lot of folders, such as `%Windir%/WinSxS` I have implemented the progress indicator (the work isn't final yet, but this is how I would want). It works too, but it doesn't update the ui.

I know that the task updating progress indicator has to run in another thread (other than javafx thread). So I have tried `Thread`, `Platform#runLater`, `CountdownLatch` etc (*it Is possible that I might have implemented it the wrong way*). But I am either unable to update the progress indicator ui or run into **`Concurrent Modification`** error. Below is my code so far of the class (with one of my many attempts):

```
class FileTreeItemImpl extends TreeItem<String> {

private boolean isLeaf = false;
private boolean childrenCached = false;
private boolean leafCached = false;
// File is basically one of root dirs
private final File file;
// pi is passed as constructor from the controller class (in which pi is injected via FXML)
private volatile ProgressIndicator pi;
// This is to control pi's progress
private static volatile double x = 0;

public FileTreeItemImpl() {
    this("Root", new File("/"), null);
}

public FileTreeItemImpl(String file, File fileObj, ProgressIndicator pi) {
    super(file);
    this.pi = pi;
    this.file = fileObj;

}

@Override
public ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> getChildren() {
    if (!childrenCached) {
        childrenCached = true;
        if (file != null && file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                x = 0;
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (File childFile : files) {
                            pi.setProgress(x / (files.length - 1));
                            x++;
                            if (childFile.isDirectory())
                                getChildren().add(new FileTreeItemImpl(childFile.getName(), childFile, pi));

                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }
    }
    return super.getChildren();
}

@Override
public boolean isLeaf() {
    if (!leafCached) {
        leafCached = true;
        isLeaf = file.isFile();
    }
    return isLeaf;
}

}
```

Note: The above code does exactly what I want but until the number of child folders of that directory are low. If there are too many (again, like in `%winddir%/WinSxS`), then I get the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

EDIT:
In any case, here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:386)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:355)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeItem.updateExpandedDescendentCount(TreeItem.java:892)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeItem.getExpandedDescendentCount(TreeItem.java:880)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeItem.updateExpandedDescendentCount(TreeItem.java:894)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeItem.getExpandedDescendentCount(TreeItem.java:880)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeItem.updateExpandedDescendentCount(TreeItem.java:894)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeItem.getExpandedDescendentCount(TreeItem.java:880)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeItem.updateExpandedDescendentCount(TreeItem.java:894)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeItem.getExpandedDescendentCount(TreeItem.java:880)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeUtil.getExpandedDescendantCount(TreeUtil.java:40)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeUtil.updateExpandedItemCount(TreeUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeView.updateExpandedItemCount(TreeView.java:1042)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeView.getExpandedItemCount(TreeView.java:614)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeView$TreeViewFocusModel.getItemCount(TreeView.java:1649)
    at javafx.scene.control.FocusModel.isFocused(FocusModel.java:128)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeCell.updateFocus(TreeCell.java:557)
    at javafx.scene.control.TreeCell.indexChanged(TreeCell.java:476)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1957)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.addLeadingCells(VirtualFlow.java:1246)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1194)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1079)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar implementation of using a `ProgressIndicator` as a part of a `TreeItem`. - I solved it by using `Task` which i use to update the UI.

my `Task` implementation looks like this:

```
class ProgressWorker extends Task<Void> {

    ...

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        while (getCurrentRow() < getMaxRow()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            updateProgress(getCurrentRow(), getMaxRow());
            updateMessage(getTextMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Use `bind` to bind the Tasks progressProperty to the Indicator:

```
progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(this.worker.progressProperty());
```

Now start the worker as Thread. - And your operation as thread. 
inside of your thread, you should be able to update Task which its property is bound to the indicator.

(pretty depressing, its harder than I thought to explain this in english)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had implemented `Task` in a number of my tries, but I must have done something incorrectly. In any case, your example helped :)

Comment: glad I could help. - I also got an example implementation that might help aswell: http://pastebin.com/qxnWn8Rm (expires in one week)